# Latent Class Analysis (poLCA) Programmatically Creating Formula in R

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, rlang

I would like to programmatically select variables/create a formula for the poLCA function. The problem seems to arise when I need to use "~ 1". Otherwise, making a formula is trivial.

Below, formula_lca will work because I manually typed in the variables. I would prefer to specify the variables with code. I have left some formula attempts that have resulted in errors.

```r
if(!"pacman" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) {
  install.packages("pacman")
}
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, poLCA, caret)

data("GermanCredit")
gc <- GermanCredit

categorical_vars <- gc %>%
   keep(is.numeric) %>%
   keep( ~ sd(.x) < .50) %>%
   names(.) %>%
   sort(.)

lca_vars <- categorical_vars[str_detect(categorical_vars, "Employment|Job|Credit|Checking")]

# poLCA will not take zeroes; change values based on 1 index for each variable
gc_lca <- gc[, lca_vars] %>%
  map_df( ~ ifelse(.x == 0, 1, 2))

formula_lca = cbind(CheckingAccountStatus.0.to.200, CheckingAccountStatus.lt.0) ~ 1

as.formula(cbind(sym(str_c(lca_vars, collapse = ", "))), 1)
#> Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()): invalid formula

as.formula(paste0(lca_vars) ~ 1)
#> paste0(lca_vars) ~ 1

as.formula(paste("y ~ ", paste(cbind(lca_vars), collapse = ", ")))
#> Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE): <text>:1:36: unexpected ','
#> 1: y ~  CheckingAccountStatus.0.to.200,
#>                                        ^

set.seed(231213)
results.2 = poLCA(
  formula_lca,
  gc_lca,
  nclass = 2,
  nrep = 10,
  tol = .001,
  verbose = FALSE,
  graphs = FALSE
)
```

Edit: an easy patch would be to run:

```r
names(gc_lca) %>% str_c(collapse = ", ")
```

And copy and paste the names without the quotes. But I am still curious if it's possible to construct a formula with "~ 1" on the outside.

Comment: what is `lca_Vars`? I can give a simple example `as.formula(paste( paste0("x",1:5, collapse= "+"),"~ 1"))`

Comment: lca_vars are categorical variables I am using. But the variables aren't important necessarily. It's constructing a formula that poLCA() will take programmatically.

Comment: From my understanding, I thought poLCA did not take a "+" when constructing a formula, based on this documentation: "Model specification: Latent class models have more than one manifest variable, so the response variables are `cbind(dv1,dv2,dv3...)` where dv# refer to variable names in the data frame. For models with no covariates, the formula is `cbind(dv1,dv2,dv3)~1`. For models with covariates, replace the ~1 with the desired function of predictors `iv1,iv2,iv3`... as, for example, `cbind(dv1,dv2,dv3)~iv1+iv2*iv3`." They use `cbind()`, which I have never seen for making formulas.

Comment: what does it take?

Comment: But now it appears to work with "+" as the collapse. Thanks @Onyambu. The documentation was a little confusing. But maybe cbind() is doing something similar to formula construction?

Comment: `as.formula(paste("cbind(", paste0("x",1:5, collapse= ","),")~ 1"))
cbind(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) ~ 1`

Comment: This works! `as.formula(paste("cbind(", paste0(names(gc_lca), collapse = ","),")~ 1"))`. I didn't think to paste like this. If you post the solution, I will mark it as the answer. Thanks @Onyambu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can paste together  the names:

```
as.formula(paste("cbind(", paste0(names(gc_lca), collapse = ","),")~ 1"))
```